# Change font size of Visual Studio 2017 CE serial monitor window?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS2017 CE along with Visual Micro Pro for Arduino programming, and consequently use VS2017's Serial Monitor window quite a bit.  I recently moved to a higher resolution display, and now the serial monitor text is almost too small to read.  I tried VS's Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors settings, but there's no 'Serial Monitor' window listed.  I also tried '[All Text Windows]' but that didn't seem to have any effect either.

I also saw an old post on the Visual Micro forum that indicated that the serial monitor font size had been tied to the 'Text Editor' window settings, but changing that value didn't work either (although it *did* change the font size in the text editor window).

Any ideas how I might increase the font size in the Serial Monitor window on VS2017 CE, either through VS settings or VM settings?

TIA,

Frank

Answer (score 1):

Never mind - I found the answer.  If the Serial Monitor window is expanded far enough horizontally, a 'Terminal Font' option button appears - DOH!

Why do I always find the answer immediately **after** embarrassing myself by asking a stupid question on a public forum? ;-)

Frank